# Possible to do Real-Time Closed Captioning using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, caption

GOAL:

- Real-Time Closed Captioning via ffmpeg

My setup:

- Real-Time video from "touchdesigner" shared via "spout" to "ffmpeg" `ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="SpoutCam"`
- The srt subtitle file below encoded with ffmpeg via `... -sub_charenc CP1252 -i test.srt ... -c:s:0 mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng`

> 1
>
> 00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:05,000
>
> Subtitle text to be updated on the fly

- I'm trying to update the srt file on the fly in order for the new subtitle-text to get encoded and muxed the into an mpegts, but when using the following cmd **i'm not getting any subtitle tracks in VLC**.

  `ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="SpoutCam" -sub_charenc CP1252 -i test.srt -map 0:v -map 1 -c:s:0 mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234?pkt_size=1316`

And when inspecting the mpegts-stream with another instance of ffmpeg, i see the subtitle stream is still there but empty or with a wrong/different encoding:

> Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://127.0.0.1:1234?pkt_size=1316':
> Duration: N/A, start: 394.666278, bitrate: N/A   Program 1
> Metadata:
> service_name    : Service01
> service_provider: FFmpeg
> Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv444p(progressive), 1024x768, 30 fps, 30
> tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
> **Stream #0:1[0x101]: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)**

Any idea if this is possible at all? And if so, what should i correct in order to get this working?

Comment: Possibly related: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/34570/can-i-inject-subtitles-into-a-live-stream-with-ffmpeg